# gm identify syntax get image width and height

Tags: graphicsmagick

I am trying to get the height and width of a jpeg image in the commandline.

I typed 
gm identify img300.jpg 
and get a long line that outputs  JPEG 3264x2448+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 1.8Mi 0.000u 0m:0.000002s

I looked in the manual for the gm command and it says I can get just the image dimensions with the -density option.

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/identify.html#ident-opti

So I tried 
gm identify -density img300.jpg 
[Option requires an arguement]

gm identify img300.jpg -density 
[no such file or directory]

debian 9, latest graphicsmagick package is the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the width like this:

```
gm identify -format %w image.png
256
```

And the height like this:

```
gm identify -format %h image.png
80
```

If you want height in a variable:

```
h=$(gm identify -format %h image.png)
```

If you want both in variables in one go:

```
read w h < <(gm identify -format "%w %h" image.png )
echo $w, $h
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, though I am still confused why the identify command didn't work.

Comment: The parameter `-density XYZ` **sets** the **density** in dots per inch of the image rather than **getting** its **width** in pixels. That's why it complains that it needs an argument - it wants to know the density you want to set.